# Spark Direct streaming with Kafka

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to implement Spark DirectStream for Kafka below is the code

```
    con = SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("Streamer")
sc = SparkContext(conf=con)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
#consumer(ssc)
kstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, kafkaParams = {"bootstrap_servers": 'localhost:9092'},topics = ['twitter'])
tweets = kstream.map(lambda line: line.decode('ascii'))
text = tweets.map(lambda line: line.split(','))
print text.collect()
```

When I run it I get the following errors. What is wrong?

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vinayaka/Desktop/BigData/HW3/SentimentAnalyser/consumer.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/vinayaka/Desktop/BigData/HW3/SentimentAnalyser/consumer.py", line 14, in main
    kstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, kafkaParams = {"bootstrap_servers": 'localhost:9092'},topics = ['twitter'])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 130, in createDirectStream
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Must specify metadata.broker.list or bootstrap.servers
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$SimpleConsumerConfig$$anonfun$9.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$SimpleConsumerConfig$$anonfun$9.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:417)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$SimpleConsumerConfig$.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.config(KafkaCluster.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitionMetadata(KafkaCluster.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitions(KafkaCluster.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:720)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler(KafkaUtils.scala:688)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's `bootstrap_servers` ? I think it should be `bootstrap.servers`

`kstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ['twitter'], {"bootstrap.servers": 'localhost:9092'})`

You can look [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/streaming-kafka-integration.html) for more details. Make sure you go to python tab.

Comment: i tried kafkaParams = {"bootstrap.servers": 'localhost:9092'} and kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": 'localhost:9092'}. Still get the same error.

Comment: Did you try `kstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ['twitter'], {"bootstrap.servers": 'localhost:9092'})` ? I know they are same but just in case